# Word CAddin - SetProperty with C++

Tags: c++, mfc, ms-word, automation

Using Word automation in C++ MFC via Machine generated IDispatch wrapper class(es) created with Add Class from Typelib Wizard, I can start Word with

```
CApplication word;
word.CreateDispatch(_T("Word.Application")
```

and open a document and save it as PDF.

Unfortunately I need to disable a Word addin that captures the Save function and prevents me from saving as PDF. I should be able to disable this by setting the Connect property of the COMAddin object to false. I can see a function that returns the COMAddIns list.

CAddIns addins = word.get_COMAddIns();

I need to step through this array and find the right Addin.

```
CAddIn addin;

for (short i = 1; i < addins.get_Count(); i++)
    {
    addin = addins.Item(COleVariant((short)i));
    CString name = addin.get_Name();
    if (name == L"ProjectWise iDesktop Integration")
    {
          // set connect property ??
    }
```

The problem arises when I want to set the connect property of the addin, whcih ought to look like this.

```
addin.SetProperty(pDisp, vtProp, propVal);
```

But I am lost for what to put in the SetProperty parameters DISPID pDisp and VARTYPE vtProp, and propVal...

dwDispID
Identifies the property to be set. This value is usually supplied by ClassWizard. ( but I haven't found this anywhere )

vtProp
Specifies the type of the property to be set. For possible values, see the Remarks section for COleDispatchDriver::InvokeHelper. This would be VT_BOOL ?

propVal 
would be false

Any suggestions would be welcome.

NB. There seem to be 3 different ways to Automate Word - the one I am trying to use is number 3 - which ought be the easiest, but also seems to be the worst documented.

1. Automating Word using the #import directive and smart pointers
2. Automating Word using C++ and the COM APIs
3. Automating Word with MFC

(this is with MSWord 2010 and Visual Studio 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AddIns is an object.

It has the members Count and Item that you can use.  I imagine it is also supports IEnumerable which means you can enumerate AddIns.

But, based on the Count member, probably get_Count() in C++, and Item, probably get_Item(), you should be able to get to the AddIn you want.

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable a addin you should use the Connect property, don't you have a put_Connect that receives a BOOL ?

Comment: I have  put_Installed(BOOL newValue) - but no put_Connect... But I only need to disable the addin temporarily.

Comment: Isn't your addin variable a COMAddIn ?

Comment: It's a CAddIn, which is what Add Class from Typelib Wizard gives me -  I don't know what the difference between a COMAddIn and a  CAddIn is ...

Comment: You need to work with "COMAddIns" and not with the "word" addins, if I'm not mistaken the COMAddin is in the office type library  (MSO.DLL)

Comment: oh I see - I am in a twisty maze of passages all alike :)  I will try with the COMAddins.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here was that I had the wrong Addin object - there is a Caddin in the Word library ( MSWORD.OLB ) and a CCOMaddin in the Office library (MSO.DLL), and I needed the second as João pointed out.

Note that when getting the objects through Add Class from Typelib Wizard, you have to comment out an #import line at the top of each .h file, which otherwise causes hundreds of compile errors.

```
// #import "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\MSWORD.OLB" no_namespace
```

The following code will start word, disable a particular addin, open a Word file and save it as a pdf, and then reenable the addin and close the file and Word.

```
#include "CApplication.h"
#include "CDocuments.h"
#include "CDocument0.h"
#include "CCOMAddin.h"
#include "CCOMAddins.h"
// START WORD 

CApplication word;


if (!word.CreateDispatch(_T("Word.Application")))
{
        return 1;
}

word.put_Visible(true);

 // disable PW i Word to allows us to save to PDF
CCOMAddIns addins = word.get_COMAddIns();
CCOMAddIn addin;

for (short i = 1; i < addins.get_Count(); i++)
{
    addin = addins.Item(COleVariant((short)i));
    CString name = addin.get_Description(); // changed from get_name
    if (name == L"ProjectWise iDesktop Integration")
    {
    // We found our addin - switch it off
        addin.put_Connect (false);
        break;
    }
}
// get the document list.
CDocuments docs(word.get_Documents());
COleVariant varOPt(DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);  // unused param

// Open a Word doc
CComVariant Filename = _T("C:\\TEMP\\PW_PDF_TEST.DOC");

// OPEN the file
CDocument0 doc = docs.Open(&Filename, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt);


CComVariant PDFname = _T("C:\\TEMP\\PW_PDF_TEST.PDF");
CComVariant PDFformat = 17;

// Save as PDF
doc.SaveAs(&PDFname, &PDFformat, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt, varOPt);

// reenable the addin
addin.put_Connect(true);

addins.DetachDispatch(); // - release objects 
addin.DetachDispatch();  // - I don't know if this is necessary

// Close Document
doc.Close(varOPt, varOPt, varOPt);

// Exit Word
word.Quit(varOPt, varOPt, varOPt);
```

My attempt to understand Word automation was made more difficult because there are at least three different ways to do it, and my searches kept returning related but irrelevant information.

Disclaimer. I have only a marginal aquaintance with C++